# Server not receiving data / Client not sending data

Tags: java, networking, socket.io, client-server

I am making a chat program. The problem occurs during the connection phase. Theoretically, the connection happens this way:

1. [Server] accept() incoming connection
2. [Client] attempt connection to the server
3. [Server & Client] initialize IO
4. [Client] send the username with a suffix indicating if there is or not a password following
5. [Server] receive username, check if there is an incoming password (if there is, read it too)
6. [Server] Check in database if client is already registered
7. [Server] ... (multiple checks of the client's account, etc...)
8. [Server] send an answer to the client if he is accepted or not
9. [Client] receive the answer and interpret it

Note that steps 6 and 7 are not yet implemented and the server skips to directly creating a new client account and accepting it in the network.

Now, something happens at either step 4 (if the error comes from the client not sending it's name) or at step 5 (if the error comes from the server not receiving the name), in either case, the server gets stuck waiting for the client's name and the client gets stuck waiting for the server's answer (step 9). I am asking your help in finding the cause of this bug and how to fix it.

Here is the code of the function used by the server to accept new connections:

```
public void establishConnection() {
    Socket client = null;
    BufferedReader input = null;
    PrintWriter output = null;
    String name = null;
    String password = null;

    try {
        client = server.accept();
        System.out.println("A connection is being established");
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());

        //LOCATION OF THE BUG
        //DESCRIPTION: If the name has been sent, the server seems not to receive it.
        System.out.println("Waiting for the client's name...");
        name = input.readLine();
        if (name.charAt(name.length() - 1) == Keywords.PASSWORD) {
            System.out.println("Waiting for the client's password...");
            password = input.readLine();
        } else
            System.out.println("The client has no password");
        name = name.substring(0, name.length() - 1);

        System.out.println("Creation of the metaClient");
        MetaClient metaClient = new MetaClient(name);
        if (password != null)
            metaClient.setPassword(password);
        metaClient.setSocket(client);
        System.out.println("Activating listening thread");
        metaClient.activateCommunications(this, this);

        /* If there is no already registered clients,
         * the first to connect shall be the owner.
         */
        if (clientsList.size() == 0)
            metaClient.addRight(MetaClient.OWNER);

        clientsList.add(metaClient);

        output.write(Keywords.CONNECTION_ACCEPTED);
        System.out.println("The connection process of user " + metaClient.getName()
                + " is complete.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error when establishing a new connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
            if (output != null)
                output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error when closing the IO of the new connection.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the builder of the client that tries to connect to the server:

```
public ChatClient(String ip, int port, String name, String password) throws ConnectException {
    this.name = name;
    boolean connectionRefused = false;
    try {
        System.out.println("Establishing connection to the server...");
        server = new Socket(ip, port);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream());

        //LOCATION OF THE BUG:
        //BUG DESCRIPTION: The name seems not to be sent to the server
        System.out.println("Sending name to the server...");
        if (password == null || password == "") {
            name += Keywords.NO_PASSWORD;
            output.println(name);
        } else {
            name += Keywords.PASSWORD;
            output.println(name);
            System.out.println("Sending password to the server...");
            output.println(password);
        }

        System.out.println("Waiting for the server's response...");
        //Wait for the server's response
        String response = input.readLine();
        if (response.equals(Keywords.CONNECTION_ACCEPTED))
            System.out.println("The connection has been accepted");
        else
            connectionRefused = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error when connecting to the server");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    if (connectionRefused)
        throw new ConnectException("The connection was refused by the server");
    else {
        communication = new CommunicationProtocol(server, this, this);
        communication.start();
    }
}
```

Any help would be really much appreciated, it makes quite some time now that i'm trying to fix this to no avail.

Edit to answer Scary Wombat's comment:
Yes, one machine runs the server and another runs the client. But the error happens even when both are running as two separate programs on one machine.

Comment: are the client and server in two different processes / threads?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I made an edit to the post to explain how it is ran. In short: yes. They are actually running in two diffirent applications, one for the end user and one for the network owner.

Comment: and what errors are thrown?

Comment: @ScaryWombat No errors are thrown, both just keep waiting for the other's name/answer. readLine() is a blocking fonction that waits for all the information to be arrived before continuing. If you mean the ConnectException that the client's constructor can throw, it is thrown if the server refuses the connection, usually because the client has been banned or is part of a blacklist.